# Rails 7.0.4 ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've started a new ruby 3.1.2 + Rails 7.0.4 app and I'm deploying from Ubuntu 22.04 to Debian 11. I'm using capistrano, nginx, passenger, rbenv as part of my stack.

The error I'm getting when deploying is;

```
00:04 deploy:assets:precompile
  01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile
  01 rake aborted!
  01 ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
  01 /var/www/profile/shared/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:209:in `rescue in _decrypt'
  01 /var/www/profile/shared/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:186:in `_decrypt'
  01 /var/www/profile/shared/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:160:in `decrypt_and_verify'
  01 /var/www/profile/shared/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:22:in `decrypt_and_verify'
  01 /var/www/profile/shared/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:104:in `decrypt'
  01 /var/www/profile/shared/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:66:in `read'
  01 /var/www/profile/shared/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:21:in `read'
  01 /var/www/profile/shared/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:33:in `config'
  01 /var/www/profile/shared/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:48:in `options'
```

I've tried the following to fix it so far;

1. Created credentials using `bin/rails credentials:edit`
   (commit, and deploy)
2. Created a production key and copied it over to production and configured capistrano to link that in
3. Configure production to use master key instead of production.key. I first removed the production.key I created in the last step, copied over my master.key to production shared area and added to linked_files to copy that in. This also failed.
4. Tried changing key generator hash from SHA256 to SHA1 (also didn't work) with the following

   config.active_support.key_generator_hash_digest_class = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1
5. Recreating credentials.yml.enc and master.key again from scratch and copying over the master.key to production and redeploying, also fails.

**Update #1: Tried using production.key instead**

I've tried creating a production key and I still get the same error on deploying.

Steps taken on my development box were;

```
$ rails secret
$ EDITOR=mg rails credentials:edit
$ rails credentials:edit --environment production
$ RAILS_ENV=production rails c
$ scp config/credentials/production.key 10.1.1.6:/var/www/profile/shared/config/credentials/
$ git add .
$ git ca -m 'Add production encrypted file'
```

Added the following to my deploy.rb

```
append :linked_files, 'config/credentials/production.key'
```

Then deployed

```
$ cap production deploy
```

I checked the release after deploy on the server and the production key file was properly linked from my shared config credentials area.

**Update #2: Create production.yml.enc on production server**

Just to test I logged into the production server and did the following commands;

Created production.yml.enc

```
$ cd /var/www/profile/releases/20221221021047
$ rm config/credentials/production.*
$ EDITOR=mg rails credentials:edit -e production
```

Test with rails console which wasn't working before, this now worked

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rails c
```

Back on development box, I copied the new key from production, commited and deployed.

```
$ scp 10.1.1.6:/var/www/profile/releases/20221221021047/config/credentials/production.yml.enc ~/code/profile/config/credentials
$ git commit -am 'Updated production encrypted yaml with server generated one'
$ cap production deploy
```

Now I don't get the error on deploy (I still get it through nginx even after restarting nginx).  It doesn't feel like this is the correct way to do this.

**Update #3: remove .rbenv-vars file**

I noticed that the documentation I was following got me to create a .rbenv-vars file on the production system. This was creating issues on my deploy. I remove the file and then I could create the production file and copy the production.key over and it now works, even in nginx.

```
  - [X] DEV: Create production.yml.enc on dev and commit
    : $ rm config/credentials/production.yml.enc
    : $ scp config/credentials/production.key 10.1.1.6:/var/www/profile/shared/config/credentials/
    : $ rake secret
    : $ rails credentials:edit --environment production
    Enter in 'secret_key_base: <secret numbers from rake secret command>'
    : $ g ca -m 'updated production encrypted file with secret again'
    : $ cap production deploy
```

Comment: Rails now uses AES 128bit for digests. Changing it to SHA1 is an exceptionally bad idea as it is very weak. I think where you're going wrong here is that you should be using `rails credentials:edit --environment production` so that you're encrypting the credentials with your `production.key` instead of your master key. https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/10/10/rails-6-adds-support-for-multi-environment-credentials.html

Comment: @max Just tried with production.key and get the same error. I understand SHA1 is bad, but was just trying anything to get the deploy working and then I can improve the process.